# symfony2.8 and twig fileloader

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Hello after upgrading to symfony2.8 i got error strange error

```
ERROR - The template "XYZ:Rendering:sometemplate.html.twig" contains an error: Warning: file_get_contents(/home/serwer1/public_html/domain/src/XYZ/CongregationBundle/Resources/views/Rendering/weekendPlansPrototype.html.twig): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

and many other errors regarding that twig fileloader cannot load template.
Admins from hosting say that part of path `/home/serwer1/public_html` is not correct meaning it should not be there.

`vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\FileSystem.php` on line 151:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSourceContext($name)
{
    $path = $this->findTemplate($name);

    return new Twig_Source(file_get_contents($path), $name, $path);
}
```

`findTemplate` returns wrong path, but inspecting it i can't see where it adds `/home/serwer1/public_html`

someone had similar issue ?

Comment: Is that file path name correct? I mean `serwer1`. Maybe supposed to be `server1`?

Comment: Look at symfony log files maybe some info can help you.

Comment: I will look at logs toomorow

Comment: @AlvinBunk the path is autogenerated

Comment: It is maybe obvious but did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes few times , tried warmup also

Comment: After upgrading to symfony 3.2.1 error disappeared